# Detect if a file is opened by any program using Python

Tags: python, linux, file, ubuntu

Is it possible to check if the file is opened by any program/user in **Ubuntu** using Python?

I want to walk over files inside a directory and delete not opened ones.

```
for _dir,folders,files in os.walk('/home/milano/folder/'):
    for file in files:
        # delete this file if not opened (for example if not opened in Libre Office)
```

**Libre Office** creates `lock` files but I want this to be universal so it works for `mp3`, `txt`, `jpg`, `xlsx` - any filetype.

PS:

The best would be if this worked on **Windows** also.

Comment: Generally this is impossible, since a program that has a file "open" might have just read it then closed it.

Comment: A question is: why do you want this? It's likely that whatever problem you are trying to solve, can be solved differently (and better), or has already been solved.

Comment: Linux has advisory and hard locks, but both are optional, so an open file may have no lock. Windows has a different locking mechanism.